# How to calculate a surface integral on a helicoid?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I have to calculate $$\iint_S \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \,dx\,dy$$ where $S$ is a 3-D helicoidal surface defined by :

\begin{align}
x&=3v\cos(\theta)\\
y&=3v\sin(\theta)\\
z&=2\theta
\end{align}
with $$0 \le v \le 1$$
and $$0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

What I would do : replace $x$ and $y$ by there parametric representation inside the integral, change the bounds also but I am stuck with the Jacobian... How to calculate it in this case, as going from 3 to 2 variables ?

Thanks

Comment: If the domain is a surface, why there is $dxdy$ instead of, say, $d\sigma$?

Comment: You can't change from 3 variables to 2 variables. The change of variable theorem says that the number of variables must remain the same. (otherwise what you defined is not even a diffeomorphism)

Comment: @Mark It's the question I face... Actually, they say it's the parametrisation of an helicoidal surface...

Comment: I don't understand why you need the variable $z$ if the integral is just on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Mark So how would you proceed ? Could you please elaborate an answer ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question well enough. I see it's a surface integral. I got confused because you wrote Jacobian. It's not a Jacobian here, it's simply the cross product of the derivatives of the parametrization by $v$ and $\theta$. I'll write an answer if you want.

Comment: @Mark Yeah sure interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parametrization $r(v,\theta)=(3vcos(\theta),3vsin(\theta),2\theta)$. Now by simple calculation:

$r_v=(3cos(\theta),3sin(\theta),0)$

$r_\theta=(-3vsin(\theta),3vcos(\theta),2)$

Now you need to calculate the cross product of the vectors $r_v\times r_\theta$. Also note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=3v$. So then your integral will be:

$\int_0^1\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}3v||r_v\times r_\theta|| d\theta dv$.

Comment: Yes thanks I remember now :)